# Need help on setting value fetched from db to list

Tags: android

Friends,
  I need to fetch data from SQlite Db and set it on List View,it fetches data has well but the view showing on screen being empty,anybody help me to get the content to visible.

Answer (score 0):

For simple String values use an *ArrayAdapter*, for custom UI on the lists, create your own Adapter and override the **getView** method.